# How do I use TypeScript 1.4 API to write a .ts file?

Tags: typescript

Using the TypeScript 1.4 API, I'd like to generate a TypeScript file from scratch. How do I do that. It looks like can use the `createNode` methods to create the tree, but how do I get it to render?

What I currently have: https://github.com/ctaggart/TsAst/blob/emit/app.ts

```
///<reference path='../TypeScript/built/local/typescript.d.ts' />

import ts = require('typescript');

export function main() {
    var m = <ts.ModuleDeclaration>ts.createNode(ts.SyntaxKind.ModuleDeclaration);
    var nm = <ts.Identifier>ts.createNode(ts.SyntaxKind.Identifier);
    nm.text = "Blah"
    m.name = nm;

    var sf = <ts.SourceFile>ts.createNode(ts.SyntaxKind.SourceFile);
    sf.statements = <ts.NodeArray<ts.ModuleElement>>[m];

    console.log("file: "+sf.text); // sf.text is undefined :(
}

main();
```

Comment: I don't think it is answered yet. A follow-up to that thread and a rewording of this question is now here: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1651

Comment: I like the questions you are asking. Thanks for that. Removed my comment to keep this open for potential community input.

Comment: 2 years later, it looks like it is scheduled now for the TypeScript 2.2 release. https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/10786#issuecomment-265957676